# df reporting incorrect disk utilization

Tags: rhel6, df

Why `df` reporting incorrect disk utilization report

```
$ df -h /shareddata
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/share_vg-lv_shareddata
                      886G  830G   11G  99% /shareddata

  $ lsblk /dev/mapper/share_vg-lv_shareddata
  NAME                        MAJ:MIN   RM   SIZE   RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
 share_vg-lv_shareddata (dm-0) 253:0    0   899.9G  0  lvm  /shareddata
```

Available data should have been `56G`

Answer (score 2):

By default 5 % of the space is reserved for root. So ordinary user may get "no space left on device" message, despite there is still 5% of space free. I belive this is the case as you have $ (user prompt) and not # (root prompt).

Comment: Plus other filesystem overhead. And I would not even be sure if the unit ``G`` is both times a power of ``1024``.